# LAN full of public ipv4 addresses - How to filter it?

Tags: linux, iptables, ipv4, internet

The answer to my question maybe is not that hard but anyways, I do not know what to do.

So, I just got in a new job in a Univerisity and I found out that the network (the LAN) is full of public IP addresses. Seriously, the whole LAN (probably more than 150 hosts) has it' own internet IP address and I don't know how to manage it.

I have a very good experience using iptables (Linux firewall) in a NAT'ed environment. But then how should I proceed in an environment where all my LAN is working with a bunch of public IP addresses? Should I just use the "forward" rules and ignore the NAT rules or is there any other issue in such environment which I should take care?

Can I add a firewall between the router and the LAN in order to produce packet filtering for these public IP addresses in my LAN or will this just not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Just because they're using public ip addresses internally doesn't mean that NAT is not happening.

Comment: A firewall doesn't need NAT to be a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alot easier without NAT. If you have experience with iptables, it should be simple: (i've used 1.2.3.0/24 as your LAN). Just use the FORWARD table.

- allow ESTABLISHED and RELATED connections (exactly same as with nat)
- allow outgoing ports 80,433,... where source address is from the local IP range (if you need to filter outgoing traffic) (-s 1.2.3.0/24 allows from source addresses from your LAN, and if you dont set the destionaton "-d", it means any destination). If you don't restrict outgoing traffic, just use "-s 1.2.3.0/24 -j ACCEPT")
- allow needed services (if you have a webserver, allow port 80 with destination ip of your webserver) (-d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80, ... if you dont set the source -s, it means any source ip)
- drop everything else

for example:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 1.2.3.0/24 -j ACCEPT #allow everything out
iptables -A FORWARD -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT #webserver
iptables -A FORWARD -d 1.2.3.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks Mulaz, unfortunately I cannot test your solution RIGHT NOW, but I should do it this week.